# Magento2.1.5: Login and registration form on login page

Tags: login, magento2.1.5, page-layouts

Is there any way to show both forms **login** and **Registration** on the login page?

> http://example.com/customer/account/login/

Which .xml layout I need to overwrite. I have done many searches on google for this but can't get a solution.

Comment: Maybe you can get idea from Magento 1 version of it - https://blog.magepsycho.com/merging-registration-form-with-default-login-page-of-magento-creating-mini-registration-form/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize login layout here

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml

Account create layout

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

**Do not edit directly core file. Copy customer_account_login.xml to your theme.**

Final customer_account_login.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- customer.form.login.extra -->
            <container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="form/login.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="loginButton" xsi:type="string">.action.login</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="form/register.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I have followed your code, but customer attributes didn't show whats the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Create `customer_account_login.xml` file in your theme and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <!-- customer.form.login.extra -->
            <container name="customer.login.container" before="customer_form_register" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="form/login.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
                <!-- <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info" name="customer.new" template="newcustomer.phtml"/> -->
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="loginButton" xsi:type="string">.action.login</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="form/register.phtml">
                <!-- <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/> -->
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```